# Partial Fraction in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a Prolog program to do partial fraction.
e.g.:- input 2/(x+1)(x+2) output 2/(x+1)-2/(x+2).

Is this possible in Prolog and what can I refer to write this program or are there any example programs I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Prolog implementations usually come with numeric constraint packages but those are very limited and can't handle a lot of basic computer algebra problems.  I've never seen one that can handle polynomials.

So basically, you'd have to implement enough of a computer algebra package to solve those problems all by yourself.  If you're good at prolog, then it wouldn't be any harder than doing it other languages - and it might be easier if you can leverage prolog's built in pattern matching and search without getting tripped up by their limitations. If you need some other kind of search than depth first, then you'll have to do some work to implement it - a lot of books on prolog will give examples.  Similarly if you need to save non-logical information about a search you'll need to do some work beyond what's natural in the language.

20 or 30 years ago someone was endlessly hawking a naively written computer algebra system as a prolog library.  As far as I could tell (and I didn't know much), the library was useless.

Comment: Library CLP(Q) is in quite heavy use, but it's about linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [algebra](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/prolog/code/math/algebra/0.html) package. Some time ago I tried to reuse it in SWI-prolog, but was not fun at all...

Anyway, I cite from simpsv.pro:

> Example of how to use the program:

```
    to simplify the expression
                                         (2*1)*(x^(2-1))
        one can

            a) simply enter
                                         s( (2*1)*(x^(2-1)), Z).
               after the Prolog prompt,
        or
            b) enter
                                          Y = (2*1)*(x^(2-1)),
                                          s( Y, Z).
               after the prompt.

        In both cases a two pass simplification is performed.
```

*edit* if you are interested, I've cleaned up the syntax, to make if acceptable by SWI-Prolog. Eventually, let me know.